# Get PDF-page-size in points with php

Tags: php, pdf

I'd like to add an item on the last page of an existing PDF. The Item is added by an commercial non modifiable API.

The positon and size is definied relative to the Page. To support diffrent page formats, I have to get the page size of the existing PDF.

I've tried it with FPDI/FPDF but there are warnings. I'm not allowed to update the version.

Next try with the TCPDF doesn't throw an exception but after the import the function getNumPages returns 0;

Is there a possibility to get the page size of a PDF without using a library or a command line tool?

Comment: Of course there is. But then you have to write a *stupendous* amount of code, including a full Deflate implementation. And you have to [rescue that princess in php](https://www.toggl.com/programming-princess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by fixing the existing fpdi library. There were only small problems with the compatibility with newer PHP Versions. I've solved them. So I could use the following snippet:

```
        $oPDF = new fpdi();
        $iPageCount = $oPDF->setSourceFile($sFileLocation);
        $mTemplateId = $oPDF->importPage($iPageCount);
        $aTemplateSize = $oPDF->getTemplateSize($mTemplateId);
```

Comment: The used property "fwPt" is an internal property of TCPDF which does not holds the size of an imported page.